# How to connect the our local chain to the frontend?

Tags: polkadot-js, api, runtime-api

I want to build a frontend for our local chain. how can we connect our local to chain to the frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can start with https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api

> The API provides application developers the ability to query a node
> and interact with the Polkadot or Substrate chains using Javascript.